# How can i update an environment variable in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have set up an environment variable in Jenkins under "Configure System" as follows:

```
   Name: programId 
   Value: 1.0
```

In the Jenkins Freestyle Project , I can echo the variable under a "Windows Batch Command" as follows:

```
 echo %programId%
```

It outputs 1.0 successfully.

But how can i update the environment variable after I echo it to lets say 2.1 ?
So if i use it anywhere else in the project it will give 2.1

Comment: use ```${YOUR_ENV_NAME}``` like this. As Jenkins will pick it up automatically as you already defined in configure system section

Comment: so if i use ${programId} = 2.1. That will set it ? and to access in my project use the same again , ${programId} ?

Comment: Yes correct. you can change like ${programId} = 2.1

Comment: But where do i set that ? It doesnt work in a Batch command ? I want it to be set back in Configure System.